# Handle externaljs DOM manipulation inside an angular7 component

Tags: events, replace, shopify, angular7

An external JS file (shopify theme editor) is replacing the contents of a div that is created inside an *NgFor, I am unable to modify this particular JS file.

When it replaces the contents of the ngFor, angular loses its bindings and is unable to process the replaced html.

I need to pass the replaced div which contained hmtl marked up and now contains JSON, back into angular to be used to recreate the angular component it replaced

I've tried NgZone run,
all standard change detection methods I could think of
handling the event but It's immutable - stopPropagation doesnt prevent it from carrying out its task

Current Lifecycle demo

```
Angular loads
Components render into html
external js fires off an ajax call and replaces the contents of "section-id-xx" with the response which is JSON
angular loses its bindings
can't do anything
```

Desired Lifecycle demo

```
Angular loads
Components render into html
external js fires off an ajax call which replaces the contents of "section-id-xx" with the json response
Angular detects the change and sucks up the json
Angular re renders the component (with the new passed JSON)
```

this is quite hairy it will be very hard to show a codepen demo but I can show a video!